# Quiz button - Incorrect counter

Tags: javascript, counter

I am trying to create a quiz where the question number will increase each time when the user clicks on next question. From there I will add more, but at the moment my counter seems off. I get 10 instead of 1 as the first number. Here is my code:

```
function nextQuestions() {
    for (var qnumber = 0; qnumber < 11; qnumber++) {
        document.getElementById('questionNumber').value = qnumber;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're replacing the element *questNumber*'s value, so it gets set with the last value in the end when the loop is finished.
So the values of *questNumber* is being changed as the loop executes:

```
value: 0
value: 1
value: 2
value: 3
value: 4
value: 5
value: 6
value: 7
value: 8
value: 9
value: 10
```

So in the end, what you see will be 10 because the previous values are being replaced.

Comment: Is there a way to fix it? Should I add in a break statement?

Comment: Depends what you're trying to achieve. Did you want a list of question numbers?

Comment: I want each number to display one at a time so I can display questions for the quiz baised on the number. Thanks for the help. I figure it might be doint that, but I wasn't sure how to fix it.